# Pytesseract is not able to read images accurately on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

Currently I am trying to run a Python program on one of my Ubuntu machines, using pyautogui to screenshot a portion of my screen and then read the text from that screenshot using opencv and pytesseract. I was able to do this sucessfully on my Windows 10 machine and it was able to read the image perfectly. However once I tried this on my Ubuntu machine the results were very different and horribly inaccurate. I'm assuming that this might be an architecture issue but I honestly have no idea. Please let me know if you have any suggestions on why this might be happening.

This is the screenshot that I'm trying to read the text from
[image: This is the image I am trying to read the text from]

This is the code for my Python Program

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract


img = cv2.imread("screenshot.png")

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img,lang="eng")
print(text)
```

(This is the code on my Ubuntu machine the only difference between the code on my Windows machine is that I specify the path to tesseract executable because it's not in my PATH but other than that it's the same code)

Output on my Windows Machine:

```
748 - Cry Me A River
```

Output on my Ubuntu Machine:

```
VL} ea wa ow WN Aois
```

Other things to note:

- Resolution is 1920x1080 on both machines
- I've tried taking the same screenshot with the same pixel measurements on both machines which resulted in the two different outputs
- I've also tried using the same screenshot image taken on my Windows Machine and sent it to both versions of the program which still resulted in two different outputs
- My Windows machine has higher specs in terms of parts compared to my Ubuntu machine. (Not sure if that plays a significant role here but I'm spitting out anything that might contribute)
- My Ubuntu Version is 22.04

Comment: Do you use the same `tesseract --version` on both machines, or is also PIL version different?

Comment: best show us samples of (clipped) data from both systems. we need to see ***exactly the same data*** that the OCR sees.

Comment: @Hermann12 I double checked the tesseract version and it seems like the method I used to install the Tesseract OCR did not install it properly. Once I reinstalled using a different method the code worked. Problem is now solved. Thank you very much for your help.